# MongoDB | Go using a pipeline to listen to updates on a document by id

Tags: mongodb, go, changestream

I'm trying to make a function that watches the database for a certain document with a certain id to update but it does not work. It just stays alive while updating the document while the function should return. I've tried multiple things and the rest of the code works fine. When i remove the id part and listen for all document updates in that collection the function does as it should

```
func iterateChangeStream(routineCtx context.Context,stream *mongo.ChangeStream, chn chan string) {
    defer stream.Close(routineCtx)

    for stream.Next(routineCtx) {
        var data bson.M
        if err := stream.Decode(&data); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        chn <- "updated"
        err := stream.Close(routineCtx)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        return
    }
    return
}

func (s Storage) ListenForScannerUpdateById(id primitive.ObjectID) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Minute)
    defer cancel()
    chn := make(chan string)


    coll := s.db.Collection("scanners")

    scan, err := s.GetScannerById(id)
    fmt.Println(scan)

    matchPipeline := bson.D{
        {
            "$match", bson.D{
                {"operationType", "update"},
                {"fullDocument._id", bson.D{
                    {"$eq", id},
                }},
            },
        },
    }

    scannerStream, err := coll.Watch(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{matchPipeline})
    if err != nil {
        err := scannerStream.Close(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            panic( err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("err: %v", err)
    }

    routineCtx, _ := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    go iterateChangeStream(routineCtx, scannerStream, chn)
    msg, _ := <- chn
    defer close(chn)
    fmt.Println(msg)
    return
}
```

Comment: What if you just write the `_id` filter like this: `{"fullDocument._id", id}`

Comment: Yes, i have already tried that, it unfortunatly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after reading the documentation for a seccond time i found this:

> For `update` operations, this field only appears if you configured the change stream with `fullDocument` set to `updateLookup`. This field then represents the most current majority-committed version of the document modified by the update operation. This document may differ from the changes described in updateDescription if other majority-committed operations modified the document between the original update operation and the full document lookup.

so after setting the fullDocument option to updateLookup like this it works perfect:

```
    scannerStream, err := coll.Watch(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{matchPipeline}, options.ChangeStream().SetFullDocument(options.UpdateLookup))
```